# Reliance on parent class attributes in mixins, and Pycharm thinking that they're unresolved attribute references

Tags: python, oop, pycharm, mixins

I'm somewhat new to mixins.  I'm building one so that I can take a bunch of optional stuff and move it to its own module.  It's intended to be used by a single class, or maybe a similar class at some point in the future.  It assumes that certain attributes of the parent class are present.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to check, from within the mixin, that the calling parent class has the assumed attributes?
2. In pycharm specifically, apparently-unresolved attributes (which exist in the parent class) are hilighted as problems.  I want to tell pycharm that this is OK, but ideally not by simply ignoring the warning but rather by sniffing somehow for the attributes of the parent class.  Is there some way to do this?

MWE:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 37

class mixin:
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = self.x + 42

class B(A, mixin):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        mixin.__init__(self)
```

The annoying hilighting in pycharm:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you are not inherited in the `maxin` class from `A class`.
also, you need to use super(..).

use this link to refresh [python-programming - inheritance](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/inheritance)

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0


class Maxin:
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = 0


class B(A, Maxin):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.x = 50
        self.y = 50


if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B()
    print(f"x = {b.x}, y= {b.y}")
```

Comment: Should a mixin always overwrite the attributes of the parent class?